# TypeError в TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Uncaught TypeError: settings is undefined**

Есть несколько полей input в которые должны заноситься настройки. Но этого не происходит.
Код компилируется без ошибок, сама ошибка появляется в консоли, то есть в js коде, если навести на settings то выдает
**TypeError: settings is undefined**.
Обычно подобная ошибка появлялась если я использовал интерфейс со свойствами которым указывал необязательную настройку (знак ?), тогда свойство было undefined | number.
Например:

```
interface IValidSettings {
      minValue?: number;
    }
```

Ошибка в консоли указывает на строку с константами.

```
@bind
  private changeSettings (settings: IValidSettings): void {
    const { minValue, maxValue, valueFrom, step, isBar, isRange, isTip, isStep } = settings;
    const components = this.components;

    components.minValue.value = `${minValue}`;
    components.maxValue.value = `${maxValue}`;

    this.changeCurrentValue(valueFrom);

    components.step.value = `${step}`;
    
    components.isBar.checked = isBar;
    components.isRange.checked = isRange;
    components.isTip.checked = isTip;
    components.isStep.checked = isStep;
  }
```

*Интерфейс который я использую:*

```
import { TValueFrom } from './types';

 interface IValidSettings {
  minValue: number;
  maxValue: number;
  step: number;
  valueFrom: TValueFrom;
  valueTo: number;
  isRange: boolean;
  isTip: boolean;
  isBar: boolean;
  isVertical: boolean;
  isStep: boolean;
}

export default IValidSettings;
```

Comment: Так может, ошибка в том месте, которое вызывает функцию changeSettings?

Comment: если компиляция происходит без ошибок - проблема не в типе. Просто данная функция вызывается с параметром `undefined`